# Cross-Site Duplicates?

Tags: discussion, questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221689/how-to-access-localhost3000-server-for-meteor-js) is about Chrome not being able to access a site running on localhost. The OP ended up finding [an answer](https://superuser.com/questions/646304/google-chrome-cant-access-localhost-domains) on SU. I can't figure out what to do:

- Flagging for migration to SU doesn't make sense, because the original question makes sense for SO (I can't get to this site I'm building)
- Cross-site dupes are not supported.

What should I do?